# Disable query validation before execution in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I believe SQL Server Management Studio validates query before execution which takes a lot of time. I have a backup query and just want to restore it to database without validation. Is it possible to have SSMS execute the query without validation?

Comment: What kind of validation? Syntax checking?

Comment: Try combination of `Ctrl + F5` - this make validation of syntax. So you will be sure that validation take a lot of time. But I am almost sure that the query itself take a lot of time.

Comment: Are you talking about syntax highlighting/intellisense/red squiggly lines in SSMS itself before you press "execute"? Or the query compilation by the server when you execute the query? How large is the query text you are loading? How much time are you talking about? How have you concluded SSMS is to blame?

Comment: what you mean when you talk about validation?

Comment: Sorry @Paolo, I mean "Parse"

Comment: By validation I mean whatever SMSS do before actually executing the query. I do not know in detail that's why I wrote 'I believe...'. And I believe because executing the same query using .NET SQLCommand takes a far less time. Therefore, it's SMSS that performs extra validations (syntax or others). I am not blaming SMSS for anything it do which it should not. I am just looking for a pass-through gate, it it exists.

Comment: Which version is your SQL Server?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Web 11.0.3000.0 @BogdanBogdanov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. Before execution there is always syntax check.

Or may be you mean preparation?

Try `[Ctrl + F5]` in SSMS to see how much takes syntax check (Parsing).

Comment: The total query lines are approx. 50K. On 100 rows, Ctrl+F5 took 4 seconds. And Execute command on the same number of rows took around 7 seconds. This 4 second time is what am trying to eliminate (I guess).

Comment: I got your point @PrashantGupta, but I am think that this is not possible. Each time you run a script in SSMS it makes `Parse` (which in your case takes 4 sec)